# How to access element's current style from directive in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive

Suppose we have the following code:

```
<div style="transform: translateX(100px);" applyTranslateZDirective><div/>
```

The directive is required to append `translateZ(...)` value to the transform property instead of overwriting it.

The end result should look like: `transform: translateX(100px) translateZ(...)`.

### Problem

The code below does not work, because `el`'s styles are **not yet initialized** when `ngOnInit()` is called.

```
///////////////
// Directive //
///////////////

private initialTransform: string;    

constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }    

ngOnInit() {
    this.initialTransform = this.el.nativeElement.style.transform;
}
```

What are the other ways to access element's **initial** style?

**P.S**

Please keep in mind, that access to other lifecycle hooks are limited, because we are dealing with directives.

Comment: you have to make use of `ngAfterViewInit`, directives addes behaviour to the component and onInit the DOM is not loaded for the directive to work

Comment: what is initial styles? a browser applies many default styles to a DOM element alongside the ones defined by a developer

Comment: @Maximus I added clarifications to the question

Comment: it is available in the constructor and hence in ngOnInit as well, `el.nativeElement.style.transform` should ouput `"translateX(100px)"`

Comment: @Maximus It doesn't. The element itself is available, however it's styles are not

Comment: can you create a plunker? it works for me